# how to add a tab dynamically when we click a particular button using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.newTabIndex = 0;
    const panes = [
      { title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1', key: '1' },
      { title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2', key: '2' },
      { title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3', key: '3' },
    ];
    this.state = {
      activeKey: panes[0].key,
      panes,
    };
  }

  onChange = activeKey => {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
    console.log(activeKey);
  };

  onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    this[action](targetKey);
  };

  add = targetKey => {
    const {panes} = this.state;
    let { activeKey } = this.state;
    if (targetKey !== activeKey){
      panes.push({title:'Tab 3', content:'Content of tab pane 3',key: activeKey+1})
      this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
    console.log(activeKey);

    }
  };

  remove = targetKey => {
    let { activeKey } = this.state;
    let lastIndex;
    this.state.panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
    });
    const panes = this.state.panes.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
    if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        activeKey = panes[0].key;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          <Button onClick={this.add}>ADD Tab-1</Button>
          <Button onClick={this.add}>ADD Tab-2</Button>
          <Button onClick={this.add}>ADD Tab-3</Button>
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.onChange}
          activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.onEdit}
        >
          {this.state.panes.map(pane => (
            <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
              {pane.content}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code. Initially I should'nt see the tab. Onclick of the button, that particular tab should pop. I could just add a similar Tab everytime. If the tab is already present then it shouldn't pop again.

Note- "antd": "^4.16.13"
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3", are the packages used.

Here is the output that I get, everytime on Click of Add button, it pops the same tab-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhHMz.png

Please help me out in adding each tab on add button click.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function instead of an object to set new state.
Cause of update of states is asynchronous and the value of state when you want change the state is not reliable.
Change the `add` method like this:

```
add = targetKey => {
  let { activeKey } = this.state;
  if (targetKey !== activeKey){
    this.setState(prevState => { 
      const newState = {...prevState};
      newState.panes.push({title:'Tab 3', content:'Content of tab pane 3',key: activeKey+1});
      return newState;
    });
  }
};
```

Also change the remove method like this:

```
remove = targetKey => {
  let { activeKey } = this.state;
  let lastIndex;
  this.setState(prevState => { 
      const newState = {...prevState};
      newState.forEach((pane, i) => {
          if (pane.key === targetKey) {
            lastIndex = i - 1;
          }
      });
      const panes = newState.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
      if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
          if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
          } else {
            activeKey = panes[0].key;
          }
      }
      return ({panes, activeKey});
  });  
};
```

check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/w71yLn24/

Comment: On changing same Tab-3 is adding twice.

Comment: Initially I shouldn't get any tab, only after I click Add it should pop.

Comment: Could you please help me out in creating a tabbar similar to code editors like- vs code, sublime, atom. Where we click on particular option on side navbar, it pops up.

Comment: Check the link that I attached to my answer

Comment: Sure I will go through.@davood Sandoghsaz

Comment: on closing one tab all the tabs, buttons are closing what to do?

Comment: How to hide the tabs initially before adding the tabs?